# Delphi XE5: Deployed file not found on android device

Tags: android, delphi, delphi-xe5

I am trying to write a small app using delphi xe5. The app has a `TClientDataSet` that I try to LoadFromFile on my android device.
Before loading I check if the file is really present with

```
if not fileExists(...)
```

I deploy the corresponding xml-file (biolife.xml) to the "assets\documents" folder.

The problem is, even though I see that the file is present on my android device (using ES File Explorer) the file is not found by the app.

What am I missing?

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 2):

The deployment path is wrong.
->It should be **assets\internal** for Android Devices!
In your code you should use :

```
{$IF DEFINED(iOS) or DEFINED(ANDROID)}
   xxx := 
      TPath.Combine(TPath.GetDocumentsPath, 'YOUR DEPLOYED FILE');
  {$ENDIF}
```

[DocWiki Delphi XE5 SQLITE Deployment](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE5/en/Mobile_Tutorial%3a_Using_InterBase_ToGo_%28iOS_and_Android%29#Deploy_InterBase_ToGo.2C_dbExpress_Driver.2C_and_the_Database_File_to_mobile)